# Why is a double semicolon a SyntaxError in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error, language-lawyer

I know that semicolons are unnecessary in Python, but they can be used to cram multiple statements onto a single line, e.g.

```
>>> x = 42; y = 54
```

I always thought that a semicolon was equivalent to a line break. So I was a bit surprised to learn (h/t [Ned Batchelder on Twitter](https://twitter.com/nedbat/status/709326204051005440)) that a double semicolon is a SyntaxError:

```
>>> x = 42
>>> x = 42;
>>> x = 42;;
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 42;;
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I assumed the last program was equivalent to `x = 42\n\n`. I’d have thought the statement between the semicolons was treated as an empty line, a no-op. Apparently not.

**Why is this an error?**

Comment: A semicolon is not equivalent to a newline, otherwise stuff like `if condition:;` would also be legal, but it is not.

Comment: @tobias_k No, it would not be legal. You would need a 'pass'. But 'if condition:;pass' doesn't work too.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be an error? There's no reason to write code like that and it'll likely confuse whoever reads it next, so isn't making it outright illegal (preventing you from making a typo and thereby leaving your coworkers to wonder what the effect of the double-colon syntax is when they see the code) a helpful thing for Python to do?

Comment: Would you expect `print [1, 2,, 3]` to work? It's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

From the Python grammar, we can see that `;` is not defined as `\n`. The parser expects another statement after a `;`, except if there's a newline after it:

```
                     Semicolon w/ statement    Maybe a semicolon  Newline
                          \/     \/               \/                \/
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)*        [';']            NEWLINE
```

That's why `x=42;;` doesn't work; because there isn't a statement between the two semicolons, as "nothing" isn't a statement. If there was any complete statement between them, like a `pass` or even just a `0`, the code would work.

```
x = 42;0; # Fine
x = 42;pass; # Fine
x = 42;; # Syntax error

if x == 42:; print("Yes") # Syntax error - "if x == 42:" isn't a complete statement
```

Comment: You could also say it's because the nonterminal small_stmt is not nullable, i.e. the empty string (epsilon) does not match small_stmt. This is the case in other languages.

Comment: maybe a typo: Syntax error - "if x == **2**:"  maybe should be 42?

Answer (score 22):

An empty statement still needs `pass`, even if you have a semicolon.

```
>>> x = 42;pass;
>>> x
42
```

Comment: But an empty line can be parsed without a pass, so this answer doesn't explain the difference between a line break and a semi colon

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - I said an empty statement, not an empty line.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. It might worth making the distinction clearer, that it requires a statement which is different to a line.